# C# DbSet (Npgsql) Function property

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, npgsql

I have a function in SQL that returns a number. This function is called `some_number`.
I also have a `DbSet<Table>`:

```cs
class Table {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to give the Table a property that is a placeholder for a function call:

```cs
class Table {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SqlFunction<string> some_number { get; set; }
}
```

If i now query a row in the table, every some_number column is the result of the some_number function in sql.

Is something like that possible? Maybe with some additional linq?
Help appreciated.

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore?

Comment: Not really answering to the question, but as an alternative, you could create a SQL view using this function. DbSet would be easier to write (and I think such a function should not be exposed outside the db).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in EF CORE with `[DbFunction]` attribute

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    [DbFunction("dbo", "some_number")]
    public static string SomeMethod() 
    {
      return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
var result = context.Table.Select(t => new Table {
    Name = t.Name,
    some_number = YourDbContext.SomeMethod()
});
```